# PHP Xdebug v3.0.0 no funciona con el depurador de visual Studio Code

Tags: php, laravel, vscode, test, xdebug

He estado intentando configurar xdebug para visual studio code pero no he podido lograr que funcione utilizo XAMPP como suite de servicios.
he seguido los pasos de ver el phpinfo copiarlo y pegarlo en sitio web [xdebug.org/wizard](https://xdebug.org/wizard) me aparece el siguiente resultado:
[image: Ya me detecta que esta instalado xdebug]
En el archivo **php.ini** agrego la siguiente configuración:

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_log="C:\xampp\apache\logs\xdebug.log"
xdebug.remote_port=9900
```

En un [video de Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNIvugvmCyQ&t=245s) comenta que en la ruta *C:\xampp\php\ext* viene un archivo con el nombre *php_xdebug.dll* este archivo se debe de eliminar y el archivo que descargue de xdebug.org debe ser renombrado con mismo nombre *php_xdebug.dll*, después se tiene que reiniciar el servidor apache, se revisa de nuevo phpinfo y debe de aparecer la extensión xdebug habilitada.

Después se instalo en VS la extensión **PHP Debug**
[image: xdebug markeplace VS]

Se creo un script de prueba y se agrego un breakpoint, al momento de ejecutar el depurador se genera un archivo json *`(launch.json)`* cuyo contenido es el siguiente:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9900,
            "runtimeExecutable": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9900,
            "runtimeExecutable": "C:\\xampp\\php\\php.exe"
        }
    ]
}
```

modifique el puerto para coincidir con el que se puso en el archivo php.ini y descartar conflicto en los puertos por si este fuese usado por otra aplicación cambiando el puerto 9000 por el 9900.
aun asi con todo eso no funciono.
[image: Ejecutando xdebug]

por ultimo ejecute el comando `netstat -na | find "9900"` para verificar si existe una conexión con este puerto, y si que la hay:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ya de ahi me quede sin ideas que 
agradezco toda la ayuda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al fin he encontrado la solución, Xdebug se actualizo de la versión 2 a la 3 por lo tanto el archivo de configuración de php.ini cambia pasando de

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = "php_xdebug-3.0.0-7.4-vc15-nts-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
xdebug.remote_log ="C:\tools\xdebug.log"
```

a :

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.0-7.2-vc15-x86_64.dll
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
```

ademas el puerto paso de **9000** a **9003** asi que hay que cambiarlo en el archivo *launch.json* que se genera en VS

Answer (score 0):

He tenido mucha dificultad para conseguir que me funcionase el debugger. Finalmente en este post he encontrado la solución. Esta claro que el problema esta en la parte de la configuración del php.ini.
No sabría decir con exactitud cual ha sido el problema porque he hecho varios cambios, pero adjunto la configuración que finalmente me ha funcionado a mi

```
[XDebug]
zend_extension = C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-3.0.4-8.0-vs16-x86_64.dll
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
```

El puerto que me ha quedado funcionando ha sido el 9003. Durante todo el proceso de intentos he probado varios pensando que pudiera ser el puerto, pero al final por lo que se ve no era.